# How do I integrate Square payments into the shopping cart of my custom website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, square

I have integrated the Square Payments API into my website successfully. But right now, it seems that it is only able to charge 1 amount and 1 quantity. I need to make it so that when the user updates the quantity of the items in their cart -- the price also goes up and that price is what is charged to their card.

I have built a shopping cart in my custom website that updates a Total Price when quantity is increased, or decreased. Now I just need to figure out how I am supposed to link the Payments API to the Total Price, so that the customer is charged that amount. Please help.

script in payment.html

```
      // Create and initialize a payment form object
      const paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
        // Initialize the payment form elements

        //TODO: Replace with your sandbox application ID
        applicationId: "applicationId",
        inputClass: 'sq-input',
        autoBuild: false,
        // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
        inputStyles: [{
            fontSize: '16px',
            lineHeight: '24px',
            padding: '16px',
            placeholderColor: '#a0a0a0',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }],
        // Initialize the credit card placeholders
        cardNumber: {
            elementId: 'sq-card-number',
            placeholder: 'Card Number'
        },
        cvv: {
            elementId: 'sq-cvv',
            placeholder: 'CVV'
        },
        expirationDate: {
            elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
            placeholder: 'MM/YY'
        },
        postalCode: {
            elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
            placeholder: 'Zip Code'
        },
        // SqPaymentForm callback functions
        callbacks: {
            /*
            * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
            * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
            */
            cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
            if (errors) {
                // Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer console.
                console.error('Encountered errors:');
                errors.forEach(function (error) {
                    console.error('  ' + error.message);
                });
                alert('Encountered errors, check browser developer console for more details');
                return;
            }
                 // alert(`The generated nonce is:\n${nonce}`);
                fetch('process-payment', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    nonce: nonce
                  })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  alert('Network error: ' + err);
                })
                .then(response => {
                  if (!response.ok) {
                    return response.text().then(errorInfo => Promise.reject(errorInfo));
                  }
                  return response.text();
                })
                .then(data => {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                  alert('Payment complete successfully!\nCheck browser developer console form more details');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.error(err);
                  alert('Payment failed to complete!\nCheck browser developer console form more details');
                });
            }
        }
      });
           paymentForm.build();
     // onGetCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay $1.00" button is clicked
     function onGetCardNonce(event) {
       // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
       event.preventDefault();
       // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
       paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
     }

    </script>
```

server.js

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const squareConnect = require("square-connect");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Set the Access Token
const accessToken =
  "accessToken";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Set Square Connect credentials and environment
const defaultClient = squareConnect.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: oauth2
const oauth2 = defaultClient.authentications["oauth2"];
oauth2.accessToken = accessToken;

// Set 'basePath' to switch between sandbox env and production env
// sandbox: https://connect.squareupsandbox.com
// production: https://connect.squareup.com
defaultClient.basePath = "https://connect.squareupsandbox.com";

app.post("/process-payment", async (req, res) => {
  const request_params = req.body;

  // length of idempotency_key should be less than 45
  const idempotency_key = crypto.randomBytes(22).toString("hex");

  // Charge the customer's card
  const payments_api = new squareConnect.PaymentsApi();
  const request_body = {
    source_id: request_params.nonce,
    amount_money: {
      amount: 100, // $1.00 charge
      currency: "USD"
    },
    idempotency_key: idempotency_key
  };

  try {
    const response = await payments_api.createPayment(request_body);
    res.status(200).json({
      title: "Payment Successful",
      result: response
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      title: "Payment Failure",
      result: error.response.text
    });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on - http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: In the `server.js` you're using `amount: 100`. You should retrieve the amount from wherever you're saving the cart information. If you're using items, you'd probably prefer using CreateOrder (https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/orders-api/create-order) so you can actually pass in item and quantity information. Then pass in the `order_id` to the `request_body` of the `createPayment` endpoint.

Comment: @sjosey thanks for your reply. good point about the amount field. I only have 1 product to sell so that might actually work! If I had more than 1 item, I'd probably need to use CreateOrder, although CreateOrder says deprecated. I also noticed all of Square's examples use cURL, Ruby, or Python. I was hoping to just use ajax.

does Square save the order and shipping information to my dashboard? Or will I have to create a form that inputs all of that so that I can ship the product to the person? Maybe have a formspree form that sends me shipping info as well as process card payment in 1 button?

Comment: You need to do API calls from a backend server. If your AJAX call is calling a backend server (PHP, Ruby, Python, Node, etc) then that will be fine. We don't allow calling APIs from client-side as this would allow anyone to view your access token and have access to your account. Once you complete the transaction, it will be viewable on your dashboard, but you would need to ask for shipping information and pass it along as well.

Comment: Thanks -- I am using Node. I already have the payment form set up and working. would I put the AJAX call in the server.js file? And would I just include the shipping fields in with the credit card payments form? Or in the AJAX request? Do you know what a sample AJAX call would look like for the Create Payment endpoint? or Create Order endpoint? Or whichever one works best for this?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have any sample AJAX requests with this. Our walkthrough uses Node, though, so you can see how it's implemented: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/payment-form-walkthrough but not Ajax. Basically you would need to do a client-side AJAX call to the points where you're calling `CreatePayment`, or wherever you're not wanting to reload the page.